# Flink job ingests kafka data very slowly, while no resources or backpressure to slow it down. What could be the reason?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

We have 5 Flink streaming jobs that ingest and process data from 5 Kafka queues respectively. The jobs are running on the same cluster, with 1 job manager, 6 task managers and 42 parallelism. We've been monitoring the Kafka consumption from the the Kafka queues and found the Kafka consumption from one of the queue is sometimes very slow, while the others are fast. The CPU usage, memory usage and back pressure are all in low level, which indicates that it is not restricted by the resources. The Kafka connection is good and there are enough messages that are sitting in the queue. What could be reason that slow down the ingestion?

Below are some more details about the job.

1. The Kafka queue has multiple topics and each has 49 partitions. The job subscribes to these topics. Messages are uneven among topics so some partitions can be inactive.
2. The consumption can suddenly bump up when some topics received messages. Not quite sure if they are correlated though.
3. We use old KafkaSource API to read Kafka streaming data.
4. We've tried added idle timeout to the watermark strategy to handle idleness source, but it didn't help.
   https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/event-time/generating_watermarks/#dealing-with-idle-sources
5. Metrics like CPU, memory usage and back pressure are low, and no sign shows there are bottlenecks.

We'd like to understand what may cause the slow consumption. Any idea is welcome.

Comment: How are you measuring that ingestion is slow? What is the consumer lag? Are you perhaps using watermark alignment or doing any rate limiting?

Comment: Is that a parallelism of 42 per job or in total?

Comment: We measure the kafka record consumption rate and it fluctuated high and low. It can bump up to a high level and then remain in low for a long time. There are enough kafka records to consume and no resource bottleneck shown. We didn't use watermark alignment but added idleness timeout for idle source, is watermark alignment helpful here?

Comment: The jobs are running on the same cluster with total parallelism of 42.

Comment: No, I'm not recommending watermark alignment, just trying to get a more complete picture of what's going on.